# How and when should I use different database types (and where can I find them)?

Tags: database, multidimensional-array, database-design, dimensions

Recently, I was reading about the ways to optimize and best use a relational database. I was trying to fit a multidimensional array into my database and that point, and I came upon [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) about different types of database systems (for example multidimensional databases). This led me to begin researching possible implementations of a database which excels at storing multidimensional data. I found it neigh on impossible to find one. Now here comes my question: Why are the vast majority of databases relational if the data they store often isn't? Why are there extremely few easy to find multidimensional database implementations? And are there more different types of databases optimized for different types of data? If so what are some examples?

If you are advocating for a specific type of database, please include statistics and concrete examples. Please use reliable sources with your answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

--> Why are the vast majority of databases relational?
Probably because relation model has been in use from quite some time and used to fit well with most of the applications developed in the past.

With big data use becoming popular, newer models started coming into picture.

You can refer to the wiki page for a new class called NoSQL databases.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

This page gives a good overview of different types of non relational databases 
being used these days.

Comment: In addition to the link, could you describe the advantages and disadvantages of using NoSQL?

Comment: I would start with the use. If you have a critical application like financial app where there is no tolerance for error, then you should go for traditional relational Database. ACID is guaranteed there. Non Sql Databases are more relevant where data set is huge, and there is some tolerance for faults. e.g. searches. Even if u get one result less, world wont stop. So advantages: Able to manage huge datasets in  very less time, distributed computing  multiple backup's of data are possible. Disadvantages: Not 100% accurate, should not be used without consideration in critical applications.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, SQL DBMSs aren't fully relational, but they're relational enough to get many of the benefits.  The relational model offers something many other data models don't - rich powerful relations with which any associations among any number of elements can be represented.  Other popular data models usually only support directed binary relationships.

As for implementing a multidimensional array, you'll need a table with a column per dimension, make that a composite key.  Depending on what you want to store in the array, you'll need more columns or even more tables.

Comment: So is there an alternative to relational databases that makes multidimensional data easier to work with? Also could you please elaborate on why SQL DBMSs are not fully relational?

Comment: I'm not aware of any system that makes it easier than relational databases.  SQL's shortcomings are that it allows duplicate rows and have complicated rules for nulls, among other things.  See http://warriorkitty.com/articles/difference_between_t_sql_and_relational_model.pdf for more.

Answer (score -1):

I've been told the big difference between SQL and non SQL databases is that SQL databases allow you to add entries efficiently and quickly with slower look up times, while non SQL databases have slower entry times but can be queried much faster. Depending which is more important to what you're doing you can then pick which path to take!

Comment: nosql is faster at everything, but they throw out as much of the rigidity of RDBS as possible to promote speed over "safety"

Comment: Could you please add a better source than "I've been told"?

Comment: @Bohemian SQL is a loose standard that's implemented by a variety of systems with different performance characteristics.  NoSQL encompasses an even wider variety of storage structures and implementations.  Performance depends very much on actual implementations and actual content and actual patterns of use.